# Undefined index with php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

why the var in php are undefined?
code html

```
<table>
    <tbody id="table">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">SignUp</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FirstName:</td><td>LastName:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-user"></i><input type='text' maxlength="25"autocomplete="off" size="20" id="fn"></td><td><i class="fa fa-user"></i><input type='text' maxlength="25"autocomplete="off"size="20" id="ln"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><div>DjName(Username):&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i><input type='text' maxlength="25"autocomplete="off"size="20" id="us"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td><td>RePassword:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i><input type='password' maxlength="25"autocomplete="off"size="20" id="pass"></td><td><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i><input type='password' maxlength="25"autocomplete="off"size="20" id="repass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td><td>reEmail:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><input type='text' maxlength="30"autocomplete="off"size="20"id="email"></td><td><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><input type='text' maxlength="30"autocomplete="off"size="20" id="reEmai"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" id="Button">SignUp</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

code javascript:

```
var httpAjax;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)httpAjax= new XMLHttpRequest();
else httpAjax= new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
httpAjax.onreadystatechange= function(){
  if(httpAjax.readyState== 4 && httpAjax.status== 200){
  }
};
httpAjax.open('POST','signup.php',true);
httpAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpAjax.send('firstname='+document.getElementById('fn').value+
'&lastname='+document.getElementById('ln').value+
'&djname='+document.getElementById('us').value+
'&password='+document.getElementById('pass').value+
'&repassword='+document.getElementById('repass').value+
'&email='+document.getElementById('email').value+
'&reEmail='+document.getElementById('reEmail').value);
```

code php:

```
<?php
  $name=$_POST['firstname'];$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];$username=$_POST['djname'];$password= $_POST['password'];$repassword=$_POST['repassword'];$email= $_POST['email'];$remail= $_POST['remail'];
  echo $name,$lastname,$username,$password,$repassword,$email,$remail;
?>
```

it's strange. the console does not give me error and have been staying here for a long time.
I would also like an explanation of the error.thanks

> Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2
>   Notice: Undefined index: lastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2
>   Notice: Undefined index: djname in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2
>   Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2
>   Notice: Undefined index: repassword in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2
>   Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2
>   Notice: Undefined index: remail in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2

Comment: "why the var in php are undefined" which one??

Comment: " the console does not give me error" . . . "I would also like an explanation of the error." this doesnt make sense, what error are you getting?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\signup.php on line 2

Comment: Are you using the same script for displaying the form and processing the AJAX request?

Comment: yes. i use direct ajax

Comment: try echoing the REQUEST

Answer (score 1):

The content type you are sending contains a typo. It should be **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, not **application/x-www-orm-urlencoded**.

Comment: sorry. a copying error, but this is not the problem

Comment: I see. Depending on what you're using to implement the backend sending invalid content type makes the backend unable to read the request payload, unfortunately it's not a case here.

Answer (score 0):

You have the id of the last element as reEmai not reEmail this is possibly causing the issue posting the data.

Plus you don't have input boxes for email or password in the code you posted.